# mySQL insert not working - cant find the answer

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a php code that is supposed to insert into a table within my database. Ive tried everything to get this to work.

I have used a smiliar code before and that worked fine. Here is the code.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require '../scripts/php/db_connect.php';

$password = $_POST['password_entry'];

$hashPass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "")
    {
        global $link;

        if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
            $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
        }

        $theValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $theValue);

        switch ($theType) {
            case "text":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "long":
            case "int":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
                break;
            case "double":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
                break;
            case "date":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "defined":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
                break;
        }
        return $theValue;
    }
}

         $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO di_ssenisub (timestamp, username, password) VALUES (NOW(), %s, %s)",

        GetSQLValueString($_POST['username_entry'], "text"), 
        GetSQLValueString($hashPass, "text"));

          if (mysqli_query($link, $insertSQL)) {
            echo "New record created successfully $username_entry";

        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $insertSQL . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
        }

        mysqli_close($link);


    }
```

There must be something im missing here. Can anyone help me figure out what it is? Thanks.

Comment: timestamp,
         username,
         password, <- there is a typo in SQL. No need , after password and before bracket.

Comment: Rather than all this escaping and quoting, why not just use parameter binding? The engine will just do all that for you, and much more safely too.

Answer (score 1):

You put a `','` after your `password` and `;` inside your `sprintf`:

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO restaurants (timestamp,
     username,
     password,)

    VALUES (NOW(), %s, %s)";
```

The right way should be:

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO restaurants (timestamp,
     username,
     password)

    VALUES (NOW(), %s, %s)",
....
```

Comment: have updated with those changes (see original post) but still nothing. Not even errors. Just a blank page...

Comment: You checked if you don't have any special character hidded in your SQL ? Please try to put it in just one line...

Comment: @SpringheeledJack if you are getting a blank page, you must check error log first. You might have to enable some extension first.

Comment: @SpringheeledJack did you used `exit();` after the `print_r()` ? If yes, probably you forget some `;` or put another special hidded character inside your file...

Comment: Somehow the code that does work. On my other registration, works in the way I want ijt to. But only if i keep the file upload html on the page. Is there something that could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

In sprintf, had to replace ; by ,

```
     $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO restaurants (timestamp,
     username,
     password,)

    VALUES (NOW(), %s, %s)",

    GetSQLValueString($_POST['username_entry'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($hashPass, "text"));
```